# Get_selected_rows( ) в ALV после обработки пай логики экрана

Tags: abap

Я вывожу ALV таблицу в контейнер на экране. Проблема в том, что я не получаю выделенную строку с помощью `go_alv_dms->get_selections( )->get_selected_rows( )` после нажатия экранной кнопки. Однако все работает, если кнопка ALVшная (находится в статус баре ALV).

Код:

Объявление выделения при выводе ALV:

```
  ...
    lo_selections = go_alv_dms->get_selections( ).
    lo_selections->set_selection_mode( if_salv_c_selection_mode=>row_column ).
    lo_events = go_alv_dms->get_event( ).
  CREATE OBJECT go_handler.
  SET HANDLER go_handler->on_user_command2 FOR lo_events.
  ...
```

PAI логика обработки экранной кнопки:

```
go_handler->on_user_command2( gv_ok_0100 ).
```

Метод класса обработки событий on_user_command2:

```
 case gv_ok_0100.
      when 'OK'.
         ...
         lt_rows = go_alv_dms->get_selections( )->get_selected_rows( ).
         ...
    ENDCASE.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выслушав мнения коллег, поискав по интернету, я пришел к выводу, что это еще одно ограничение при использовании класса `CL_SALV_TABLE`. Переделал на класс `CL_ALV_GRID` и все заработало. Буду рад, если кто-нибудь опровергнет мое заявление, так как  `CL_SALV_TABLE` мне нравится больше.

Answer (score 0):

Если сделать вывод таблицы в конкретный контейнер на экране, то все работало бы.
Скорее всего делал просто вывод в стандартный контейнер и со старыми кнопками в статусе.